# android emulator and restful web service not working with PhoneGap

Tags: ajax, cordova, android-emulator

I've got a restful web service running and its working when I test it using the following ajax code:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#page2',
    function(){
                $('#submit').click(function() 
                {
                    var name = $("#username").val();
                    var surname = $("#usersurname").val();

                    alert(name + " " + surname);

                    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/rest/index.php/api/practice/test/name/"+name+"/surname/"+surname + "/format/json",
                    function(data) 
                    { 
                        alert(data.result);
                    });
                });         
              });
```

Now the I want to use this code to access the same restful web service but through the android emulator. Here is the code I have used in the emulator using PhoneGap:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#page2',
    function(){
                $('#submit').click(function() 
                {
                    var name = $("#username").val();
                    var surname = $("#usersurname").val();

                    alert(name + " " + surname);

                    $.getJSON("http://10.0.2.2:8080/rest/index.php/api/practice/test/name/"+name+"/surname/"+surname + "/format/json",
                    function(data) 
                    { 
                        alert(data.result);
                    });
                });         
              });
```

I've also made changes to the config.xml file as follows:

```
<access origin="http://10.0.2.2/rest/index.php/api/practice/test" subdomains="true"/>
```

The app still doesn't seem to be working. Please can someone help out

Comment: not sure about the origin line... have you tried: `<access origin="http://10.0.2.2:80080*" subdomains="true"/>`, or even `<access origin="http://10.0.2.2*" subdomains="true"/>` ? does the URL actually work on that remote server?

Comment: Thats exactly what I was missing, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the origin line... have you tried:

```
<access origin="http://10.0.2.2:80080*" subdomains="true"/>
```

or even

```
<access origin="http://10.0.2.2*" subdomains="true"/>
```

?

Comment: this answer was posted a couple of years ago - Cordova change a lot since then, including their configuration, so it might not be relevant for new versions anymore